# Regular expression to isolate text from some sample html?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm curious to find the C# regex expression that extracts the following:

```
<a id=sector href="?catid=us-58211593" >Financial</a>
```

... from this html string:

```
<div class="g-unit g-first">Sector: <a id=sector href="?catid=us-58211593" >Financial</a> &gt; Industry: <a href="?catid=us-64965887" >Misc. Financial Services</a>
```

The text "href="?catid=us-58211593" is not relevant, so it should be matching on the "a" and "id=sector" elements.

**Update**

Indeed - RegEx is just not the right tool for the job. It only took 3 lines of code from the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to achieve the required result:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument myDoc = hw.Load("http://www.google.com/finance?q=IBM");
var etc = myDoc.GetElementbyId("sector").InnerText;
```

Comment: You probably want an HTML parser as there are any number of references as to why Regex isn't sufficient to parse HTML. Check out [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). There are [better solutions](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/50-silly-rabbit-parsing-html-is-for-kids), such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: ohhhhhhh, you are so totally correct :-) I am surprised that there are still developers that consider regex a tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: Every time I see "regex" and "HTML" in a question title together, I cry a little on the inside.